# Xcode 5 hangs iOS 7.0.3 devices and logs failed to get the task for process -1

Tags: ios7, xcode5

I am not exactly sure when this started but it was around the time that iOS 7.0.3 came out and it seems to be getting worse. About every 2-3 times I run my project on a device Xcode will log `error: failed to launch '/private/var/mobile/Applications/1D114571-A4A6-4DF3-B5DE-8C7E6A627143/Client.app' -- failed to get the task for process -1` and the device will hang showing the launch image. The home button and 4 finger pinch do nothing. The lock button will turn off the screen but then you can not turn it back on. The strange thing is that Siri sort of works. The only way out of this state that I have found is to hold down the power and lock buttons until the device restarts. If I don't restart Xcode is almost always happens on the next build. Restarting the computer doesn't seems to help.

I have tried reinstalling both Xcode and iTunes. I have also done a "Erase All Content and Settings" on the devices both restoring from a backup and starting fresh.

**Update**

This appears to be a common problem on the Apple Developer Forums. This [thread](https://devforums.apple.com/message/912166#912166) suggests that the issue is Xcode 5.0.1 and suggests using Xcode 5.0 for testing.

Comment: Same thing happens to me. Did you find a way to restart the phone other than restore?

Comment: Hold down the power button and the home button for 10 seconds and the device will restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Xcode 5.0.1. Downgrade to Xcode 5 for testing. Just make sure to use the latest version when submitting to the App Store.

Apple Dev Forum thread - https://devforums.apple.com/message/912166#912166

Download old versions of Xcode from here - https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode

**Update**

This is solved with Xcode 5.0.2 and listed on the change log.

Answer (score 0):

This what helped me.

1 - Select your team in the project settings (General tab)
2 - make sure that there is no issue with provision profile for current bundle id
3 - remove all provision profile from device. (go to organiser, select device and remove all profiles)